# How can I check the size of a OneNote notebook on iPad?

Tags: ipad, onenote

I use OneNote to maintain notes on my iPad. I want to know how I can determine how much space each notebook is occupying so I know how much space is left. However, I have no way of doing this.

Also, how much free storage does Microsoft give for OneNote ?

Also, how can I link to another page in the notebook. This option seems to be missing for the iPad version ...

Any help would be very appreciated .

Thanks a lot !i

Answer (score 2):

Hi if you've taken the path of least resistance and defaulted to using Microsoft's OneDrive for storing OneNote documents,

then you can follow this route:

First make sure that OneNote documents you are interested in are synced.

On the ipad's onenote screen the 2nd icon in on the purple ribbon is a notebook,
touch that and select 'sync this notebook'
This ensures a copy is with stored on the One Drive.

Now you need a separate Apps store app to look at the OneDrive, which handily is called OneDrive.
Download that from the app store,
login to your onedrive,

You'll now be able to see your OneNote document, and the size is shown by default.

Comment: Thanks a lot . I got the app and then found the size of the notebook.